# Repeat the same search in `helm-rg`, visiting buffers between search

Tags: helm, ripgrep

I'm trying to do the following:

- find all buffers containing text "foo"
- visit each of those buffers to perform some edition

Using `helm-rg`, I'm forced to do this:

- `M-x helm-rg`
- Enter the text I'm looking for (`foo`)
- Move in the `helm-rg` buffer to the first file
- Press RET to visit the first file
- Do my edits in this first file, save the buffer
- `M-x helm-rg`
- Enter the text I'm looking for (`foo`)
- Move in the `helm-rg` buffer to the second file
- Press RET to visit the second file
- Do my edits in this second file, save the buffer
- `M-x helm-rg`
- ... etc, etc...

This gets tedious pretty quickly, and there has to be a better way.
Some research mention using `helm-follow-mode`, or `helm-resume`, but in my setup it does not change anything (`helm-resume` does nothing after visiting a file from `helm-rg`.)

What would be the smart thing to do here ?

Comment: maybe able to do with a package [wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) and possibly [wgrep-helm](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep/blob/master/wgrep-helm.el) or [Embark](https://github.com/oantolin/embark) (which can export the grep (also rg, occur, etc.) result for the other action, such as `wgrep`) together.

Comment: `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` perhaps? At least, all the matches stay in the *Occur*   buffer so you don't have to repeat the search, just choose and click the next match. And `next-error` (``C-x ` ``) works to go to the next match.